# Crosswalk for Android splash screens

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

How can I add splash screens when using Crosswalk to create the APK?

A side question, what is the crosswalk equivalent of config.xml and where do I put it?

Answer (score 1):

In Manifest:

```
"launch_screen": {
"ready_when": "custom",
"portrait": {
    "background_color": "#ff0000",
    "background_image": "bgfoo.png 1x, bgfoo-2x.png 2x",
    }
}
```

See: https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/manifest/launch_screen

Comment: Can you please tell me, how can I add manifest.json to cordova project (platform android)?

Comment: Where do I have to place this manifest file, is it a xml file or json?

Comment: please explain what to do